# Qt Creator: deselect some Qt Tests in qbs?

Tags: qt-creator, qbs

Qt Creator has the possibility to "Run Selected Tests". 
Is there any option in qbs to deselect some tests as default?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, qbs doesn't have this ability natively. However, you can select specific tests to run from Qt Creator from the "Tests" sidebar.

Alternatively, you could try to select some tests using the condition property on a group.